# How to back to begin process jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a modal form and an input field with checkbox type. I want to create an update form, so I should request data from php and passing to html. So I have two conditions, if parameter = 0 attribute checked="checked", else attribute checked become unchecked. So I use jQuery, this is my code:

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="Ya" name="agenda_pimpinan" id="tampilkan_agenda_pimpinan" checked="checked"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var x = event.tampilkan_agenda_pimpinan;
  console.log(x);
   if(x != 0) {
      $('#tampilkan_agenda_pimpinan').removeAttr("checked");
   }
   else {
      $('#tampilkan_agenda_pimpinan').attr("checked");
   }
</script>
```

Assume I have two data that I want to update, we assume the names data1 and data2. **Data1 have parameter = 0 and Data2 have parameter = 1**. If I click data1, the modal form will come in. The attribute checked has success become still checked. Next, I click data2, the attribute checked has success become unchecked. But if I back click data1, the attribute checked become unchecked. I don't know how to write code so that the attribute will back to begin.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
   var x = event.tampilkan_agenda_pimpinan;
   //$('#tampilkan_agenda_pimpinan').attr("checked");
   if (x != 0) {
      $('#tampilkan_agenda_pimpinan').removeAttr("checked");
   } else {
      $('#tampilkan_agenda_pimpinan').attr("checked");
   }
});
```

Comment: @syaifulhusein What is the problem you have now? what `event.tampilkan_agenda_pimpinan` is? value? Does your browser tell anything?

Comment: `event.tampilkan_agenda_pimpinan` contains value 0 or 1. The value as a parameter for checked or unchecked checkbox.